# Select multiple row even first table is null mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've encountered a problem on my wordpress website. I have multiple select mysql query from one page then decided to merge because it's in from same table. But the problem is when first selected table is null, all other row is affected and becomes null. And if the first select table is has a value, then the others selected  rows will be display.

Here's my sample mysql query code:

```
SELECT u1.meta_value as name, u2.meta_value as birthday,
u3.meta_value as place
FROM wp_usermeta u1 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta u2 ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta u3 ON u1.user_id = u3.user_id
WHERE u1.user_id = 1092
AND u1.meta_key = 'name' AND u2.meta_key = 'birthday' AND u3.meta_key = 'place'
```

Comment: Use `union` instead to merge the result of the queries.

Comment: thats how  left join works. It display null if the second table has no matching value for a value on the first table

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I use `union`, the last value transfer to first u1.meta_value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `union` and 2nd query as a right join below is sample code

- The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table
  (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The
  result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.
- The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more
  SELECT statements.
- Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of
  columns
     The columns must also have similar data types
     The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

  ```
      select t1.* from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
      union
      select t2.* from t1 right join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
  ```

Comment: Hi I tried your code, but the values goes to wrong column alias. ex: when "name" is null and the "place" only has value. the output become `name->japan,birthday->null, place->null`

Comment: @P.James can you give me fiddle link where you tried it